# CSS transition-delay bug in Mac Safari 5.1 -- any workarounds?

Tags: html, css

I'm experiencing a very annoying bug which appears in Safari 5.1 on Mac. Since this browser is still very common I need to support it.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QCvZt/2/

On clicking a button, a class is added to a containing element `#chance`. The stylesheet has rules that then cause the clicked element `#chance-loose-card` to animate away with transitions immediately and then, after a delay, `#chance-card` animates in.

They fade out and in with `opacity`, and I flip `visibility` to hidden when they're totally transparent, since in the full site they might otherwise be over top of things and capturing clicks meant for elements below.

This works very well in Firefox and Chrome (and Safari 6).

But in Safari 5.1 on Mac the first animation is happening as expected but then `#chance-card` isn't appearing. It's not until I hover over the `#carousel` element (presumably it's because it triggers another transition -- a button fading in) that `#chance-card` makes its appearance.

Now, given my assumption that it's to do with another transition being triggered, I tried forcing a transition to happen every second via a Javascript `setInterval` flipping a class on an element, causing it to transit back and forth. But this did not unfreeze the transition and make `#chance-card` appear. Transitioning a `transform: translate` instead of `margin-left` on the `#chance-card` doesn't help either.

As noted in the JSFiddle, reducing the `transition-delay` on `#chance-card` does make the bug go away, but for my use case this isn't an acceptable solution.

I wonder if anyone can suggest any workarounds? I haven't found anything which sounds similar in my searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution!

http://jsfiddle.net/QCvZt/4/

Changing the `transition-delay` of the `visibility` property to just less than the delays of the other properties fixes the issue. So it seems that if transitions are delayed, if `visibility` is `hidden` at the time when the transitions start (even if it's going to flip to visible at that same moment), the transitions don't start until somehow triggered (like in this case with the mouse over the grey area, though I don't know exactly the mechanism). Flipping `visibility` to `visible` just before the other transitions are due to start makes the problem disappear.

In this case I changed this (vendor prefixes omitted)

```
#chance.state-chancecard #chance-card {
    transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 0.1s, visibility 0s;
    transition-delay: 0.5s, 0.5s, 0.5s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transform: none;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

to this

```
#chance.state-chancecard #chance-card {
    transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 0.1s, visibility 0s;
    transition-delay: 0.5s, 0.5s, 0.49s; /* flip visibility just before other transitions are to start */
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    transform: none;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```